# Is any way of getting apple InApp price and region?

Tags: apple-developer

I'm working on apple server-to-server analytics system that verify apple transactions from my mobile apps. Is any way of getting price or region of `InApp` or `LatestReceiptInfo` from apple `VerifyReceipt` endpoint? Or maybe any other ways of getting price of consumable purchases and auto renewable subscriptions?